# S3 event trigger based on partition key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have my data in S3, partition by following format:

```
year=2018/month=04/day=29
```

How can I trigger an S3 event to invoke a Lambda function whenever the day value changes? Setting the prefix value to 'day' will work?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated method to do this.

You will need to trigger an event for **every** Amazon S3 object created in that hierarchy.

The Lambda function would then need to determine whether it was triggered by the first object for the day by listing objects within that that path and comparing it to the name of the object that triggered the function.